# How can I effectively profile a cygwin application?

Tags: windows, performance, profiling, cygwin

I have a cygwin application (a game: http://te4.org) that I want to profile to figure out why it's so slow on one of my machines. Since cygwin doesn't produce PDB files, the usual Windows-profiling suspects need not apply.

What's the state of the art for this sort of thing?  I haven't found many encouraging things about using gprof (requiring custom libraries to be dropped in, etc.), but I'll go there if I have to.

Comment: [This method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) might not be easy to do, but it should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I want to profile something that's interactive, so flipping back and forth to gdb at the right time is going to be a serious pain.  I've done that sort of sampling before (esp for application hangs), though, and it does indeed work if you're able to manage the timing.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Yeah, what I do then is slow down the interactive code by either 1) putting a loop around it, or 2) in the debugger, create a data-change-watch. This puts the debugger into emulation mode, 1 or 2 orders of magnitude slower than normal, which does the same thing as "speeding me up". Then of course, the problem gets found/fixed, the program is put back to normal, and it's faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin has [gprof](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/).  I don't know whether it's installed by default, but you can install it via the Cygwin `setup.exe`; it's part of the binutils package.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard horror stories about getting it to actually work (see above regarding needing to replace libc or similar). I'll give it a swing, though, thanks.